# Printing Python __str__ from an object

Tags: python, string

I have actually finished this exercise (almost) but am just stuck on a tiny problem with `__str__` which is inside an object. If i do this

```
elif choice == "9":
    try:
        for i in sworm:
            print(i)
    except TypeError:
        None`
```

Then it will only print out the details of the first object in my list (only 2 objects in there) e.g --  `sworm = [crit,crit1]`

When I tried this

```
elif choice == "9":
    try:
        print(sworm)
    except TypeError:
        None
```

Then I get:-

```
[<__main__.Critter object at 0x02B54AD0>, <__main__.Critter object at 0x02B5B190>]
```

Here is the first half of my Object

```
class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name, hunger = random.randint(1,50), boredom = random.randint(1,50)):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom



    def __pass_time(self):
        self.hunger += 1
        self.boredom += 1

    def __str__(self):

        print ("Critter object\n")
        print (self.name)
        print (self.hunger)
        print (self.boredom)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic, but note that your constructor arguments will get evaluated only once, instead of on every instance creation (see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas.html#mutable-default-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python list always shows the *contents* as representations, calling `repr()` on the objects.

You can hook into that by specifying a `__repr__` method as well. Alternatively, don't print the list directly, but only the contents:

```
for elem in sworm:
    print(elem)
```

or join them as a long string:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, sworm)))
```

*Do* make sure you actually return a value from your `__str__` method though:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Critter object\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.name, self.hunger, self.boredom)
```

because it is the *return value* that is printed by `print()`.

Comment: the same thing happens, the first solution brings up this kind of thing [<__main__.Critter object at 0x02B54AD0> and the second solution only prints one element. do i need to implement the __repr__ thing first?

Comment: I followed your instructions but this time i removed the try statement and i got this 'expected str instance, int found'

Comment: @jimmyLight: Switched to string formatting instead, which will convert all arguments to `str()` when interpolating. One or more of your `self.` attributes is an `int` and I didn't take that into account.

Comment: praise the lord! Thank you, i tried converting the elements to strings originally but i guess it needed the format command. Though how was i supposed to know this after reading 1 chapter with no mention of this. Cheers for looking at this for me.

Comment: @jimmyLight: There are multiple ways to convert your attributes to string; calling `str()` on them is one.

Comment: I tried this i think `(str(elem) + ', ')` but i must have got something mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the `__str__` method to work, then you should return a string from it - something like this

```
def __str__(self):  
    return 'Critter object: %s %s %s' %(self.name, self.hunger, self.boredom)
```

Please read the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well OP said that they had a problem with the `__str__` method, and it's `return` statement was missing. I think that's fair enough.

Comment: Yup, you are correct; the `print()` statements in the `__str__` are the best indicator of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
    print ("Critter object\n")
    print (self.name)
    print (self.hunger)
    print (self.boredom)
```

See, the __str__ method shouldn't actually **print** anything. Instead, it should **return** what it wants to be printed. So, you need to do this:

```
    return "Critter object\n\n" + self.name + '\n' + self.hunger + '\n' + self.boredom
```

Comment: This is how i did it the first time, i just tried it again with print(sworm) like the book told me and it gives this [<__main__.Critter object at 0x02B54AD0>

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you do not want to hard code your **str** properties you can do it like this

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join(['{key}={value}'.format(key=key, value=self.__dict__.get(key)) for key in self.__dict__])
```